# remove div content and add iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my application I want to remove div content and add iframe, here is my code

index.html

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" >
    <div data-role="content" id="contents">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="cif()"><img src="images/zo_connect.png"></a>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

default.js
function cif(){

```
$("#contents").remove();
$("#contents").html('<iframe src="http://google.com" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></iframe>');
```

}

when i remove div contents and after that create iframe it doesn't show, I need that after clicking button remove the contents and after that in that contents create iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you remove "contents", it's gone... You can't thereafter change its html(), since it's gone. You might want to skip the first line altogether.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#contents").remove()` removes the whole `<div id='contents'></div>`

You're looking for `$('#contents").empty()`, which will remove everything inside the `<div id='contents'>`

Comment: `.html()` calls `.empty()` (if necessary) so there is no need for that